# how to define an element of type record?

Tags: agda

I have define the datatype of real number as..

```
record ℝ : Set where
   field 
      L : Stream pair
      R : Stream pair
      inhabited : ∀ (x : pair) → ( (x mem L) or (x mem R)) 
      disjoint    : ∀ (x : pair) → ( (not (x mem L)) or (not (x mem R))) 
      located     : ∀ (x y : pair) → (x ≤pair y) → ((x mem L) or (y mem R))
```

Now I want to define an element of type **R** . I tried as..

```
mkReal : Stream pair -> Stream pair -> R
mkReal x y = record { L = x; R = y}.
```

But this is not working please help.

Comment: What error message are you seeing? How is it "not working"?

Comment: I need to give argument of type inhabited , disjoint and located ..I dont know how to write that..

Answer (score 3):

Your record `ℝ` has five fields, `L`, `R`, `inhabited`, `disjoint`, and `located`. To define an instance of `ℝ`, you have to supply values for all five fields:

```
mkReal x y = record { L = x; R = y; inhabited = ?; disjoint = ?; located = ? }
```

You will likely have to pass the values of `inhabited`, `disjoint`, and `located` as arguments to `mkReal` as well.

By the way, there is a way to automatically define a constructor for your record:

```
record ℝ : Set where
   constructor mkReal
   field 
      L : Stream pair
      R : Stream pair
      inhabited : ∀ (x : pair) → ((x mem L) or (x mem R)) 
      disjoint    : ∀ (x : pair) → ((not (x mem L)) or (not (x mem R))) 
      located     : ∀ (x y : pair) → (x ≤pair y) → ((x mem L) or (y mem R))
```

As a bonus, you can now use `mkReal` when pattern matching:

```
foo : ℝ → ?
foo (mkReal L R inhabited disjoint located) = ?
```